# Android Kotlin error on Mac M1 PRO - A failure occurred while executing org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.internal.KaptExecution

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle, build.gradle

I'm having an error when i try to build my android project, this proyect on windows works fine in android studio 4.1.1 but in mac os with M1 PRO and android studio Flmaingo 2022.2.1 throw me the following error:

`Execution failed for task ':app:kaptQADebugKotlin'.

> A failure occurred while executing org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.internal.KaptExecution
> java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException (no error message)`

i tried a lot of solutions that i found on internet but nothing works, do you have any idea?

I'm using jdk 11.0.1 with android gradle plugin 3.6.3 and gradle 5.6.4

This is my gradle file for the proyect

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        kotlin_version = '1.3.61'
        lifecycleVersion = '2.2.0-rc03'
        navigationVersion = '2.2.0-rc04'
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public'
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "androidx.navigation:navigation-safe-args-gradle-plugin:$navigationVersion"
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.3'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.2'  // Google Services plugin
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.31.2'  // Crashlytics plugin

    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public'
        }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Fortunately i still have my windows laptop so i can work the project there but i need to run the app in the mac laptop